# GPS Location returns zero speed always

Tags: android, gps, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have code that successfully gets location updates from multiple providers and filters them to give a current best estimate.

I added code to check for the returned Location.hasSpeed() and .hasBearing() values to do some bearing related calculations when the user is actually moving.

It all works fine on a Huawei Sonic running 2.3.3, but on the Google Nexus S running 4.0.4 the GPS provider's Location *always* returns false for .hasSpeed() and 0 for .getSpeed().

When I register my location listener, the GPS provider returns true for .supportsSpeed() but it never returns the speed in a Location even when the accuracy is down to 30m and it is physically moving (in a car, on the dashboard for max reception, screen on).

Is there some difference from 2.3.x to ICS 4.x? 
Do I have to implement my own speed calculation even when the provider reports support?

Comment: I have problems receiving the current location on Nexus S running Android 4.1.1
Same code is working correct on Samsung Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.0.4 and on Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.0.4
Seems to be there are some GPS issues on Nexus S devices.

Answer (score 0):

Google Nexus S has history of problems with GPS. I don't think that it's specifically related to ICS. Have you tried **Factory data reset** the phone and then retry it?

Comment: Not yet, but even if that works it is not a good result, do I suggest to my users that they reset their phone before installing my software if they have a Nexus S? Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @user1230223 Off course not, but don't you think that it's better to know whether it works like this or not?